# md5 hashes in Java from MessageDigest don't matchup

Tags: java, md5

I have an object called users that I use to store user objects that have credential information.

I call this code to make a new default user.

```
user def = new user("admin","admin",md5hash(("osa").toCharArray()),1,-1);
```

This def user is added to the array.

These users are stored inside an array. When I loop through the array to check whether it is valid or not, I use this snippet of code to output information about users inside the array, namely the username and password in string format from a byte array.

```
System.out.println(userarray.get(x).username);
System.out.println((userarray.get(x).password).toString());
```

The passwords are all encrypted in md5 and stored as a byte array using this code:

```
byte[] md5hash(char[] passwd) {
    String passwdtext = new String(passwd);
byte[] passdigest = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.reset();
        md5.update(passwdtext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        passdigest = md5.digest();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return passdigest;
}
```

When I try entering "admin" for user and "osa" for the password, I output these as well and compare them with the values in the array

I get the following:

```
admin [B@2b12e7f7
```

and compare to the value inside the array:
    admin [B@663b1f38

Why are they different?

Comment: The correct MD5 checksum for `osa` is, in hex, `43f38d003c06cca6687b5991a52787c1`. It's not clear to me how you are trying to output the MD5. Are you trying to do it in ASCII for the hex digits in lowercase?

Comment: Off topic, if you are serious about storing passwords you should at least use a random salt for the hash. Or maybe use bcrypt.

Comment: True, but this is for a school project xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toString() byte array does not encode the data. What you are looking at is the memory address of said arrays. The "[B" means byte array. The hex after that is the address.

Instead, you should invoke `Arrays.toString(digestArray);` which will print the actual values in the array.

Also, it's not clear by the code that you posted, but if you're trying to use `==` to compare the two arrays, that will fail for the same reason. The `==` operator on arrays compares memory addresses. Here again, you should use `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)` to compare.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` which is just calling [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). What you get does not represent the contents of the array but its *hashCode*, instead.

If you are looking to get an MD5 string I would suggest using [`DigestUtils.md5Hex()`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex%28java.lang.String%29) from the Apache [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) project. This replaces your whole `md5hash()` method.

If you are not keen on adding an external dependency and just want to implement this for yourself then you just have to decode a String representation for each byte value in your byte array, such as by [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5b%5d%29).